# is $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : 0\leq x \leq 1$ and $x$ is irrational $\} $ compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

is $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : 0\leq x \leq 1$  and x is irrational $\} $ compact ?

---

**Theorem** 
Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ the following are equivalent

- $A$ is closed and bounded
- Every open cover of $A$ has a finite subcover
- Every sequene in $A$ has a subsequence which converges to a point of $A$

A subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying one (and hence all) of the conditions of Theorem is called ***compact***

---

[image: picture of given set]

*(would take like more than hour to draw that on latex by the way)*

I thought at first it was compact it was throwing me off that points are closed and thought all the irrational points togheter was a closed set which is not the case.

I know this because looked at back of book of marsden "elementary classical analysis" on ex 3.1 1.a. It just says it is not compact but dosent elaborate why.

For it to not be compact it needs to fail one of the conditions of the theorem. It is not obvious to me a sequence made up of irrationals within [0,1] that converges to a point outside the given set.

can make a loose argument how second bullet point of theorem fails.could  make up an open cover consisting of union of open balls at the irrational points of the set with the radius of the smallest distance bw a point and its neighbor. and then say there is no finite subcover since the open cover is made up of infinite sets.

*wondering what is the most elegent way to put it!*

Comment: The closure of that set is the entire interval $[0,1]$, so the set is clearly not closed.

Comment: The set of irrational numbers is dense in the real numbers, and there do exists rational numbers, so the set of irrational numbers cannot be closed.

Comment: Denote your set as $A$. The set is not closed; take the sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{\pi^n}$. Since $\pi$ is irrational, each $a_n\in A$. But $a_n\to 0\notin A$, so $A$ is not closed.

Comment: @Guy: Note that taking an arbitrary irrational $z\in(0,1)$ (such as your $z=1/\pi$) and putting $a_n=z^n$ doesn't prove this. One must also have that each $a_n$ is irrational. That's truly the case for your example, but it's not enough to argue by saying that $a_0$ is irrational.

Comment: @MPW You're right; this is because $\pi$ is transcendental. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @Ugo If you believe the irrationals are closed then you also believe the rational numbers are *open* (at least, open relative to the interval $[0,1]$).  Do you really think the rationals are open?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That set is not closed, notice that $0$ is a limit point for the set and is not in the set.

Comment: Not only $0$. All rational points in $[0,1]$ are limit points for the given set.

Answer (score 1):

(i). $A=[0,1]$ \ $Q$ is not closed because if $ x\in A $ then the  sequence  $(x/n)_{n\in N}$ of points of $A$ converges to $0, $ and $0\not \in A.$ In fact the closure of $A$ is $[0,1].$

(ii). $C=\{(2^{-n},2^{1-n}) :n\in N\}$ is an infinite open cover of $A$, and no proper subset of $C$ is a cover of $A.$

(iii).  $A$ is not closed. Let $T= (t_n)_{n\in N}$ be any sequence in $A$  converging to a point not in $S$. Then $T$  cannot have a subsequence  converging to anything else, hence no subsequence of  $T$ converges to a member of $A.$

Remark. The fact that $A$ is dense in $[0,1]$ follows at once from the def'n of the real number system $R$. Without a def'n of $R$ you can't prove anything about it.

Comment: What definition of real numbers do you have in mind that makes $A$ immediately dense?  One generally defines real numbers as limits of rational numbers (one could shift them by a fixed irrational, but I wouldn't call that construction immediate).  I doubt it's true in general that if $M$ is an incomplete metric space and $S$ is the completion then $S\setminus M$ is dense in $S$.

Comment: @EricWong. The OP had thought the irrationals were closed in R and said it is not obvious to him that  A is not closed. Clearly the OP needs to study the logical foundations of the reals.